Fish shell: Completion: how to define command sub-argument completion?
I would like if it is possible to define completion for sub arguments in fish
Best explained w/ an example:
$ somecmd -k foo[arg1,arg2,..argK,.,argN]
-----------------------------^^^^
Cpmpletions for the arg1, arg2 ... argN ? Possible? How would you do it?
The general interesting case for me is that argN takes it values in a finite list (depending on K and foo)
N is variable
I have imagined some things with matching list of regexes => tedious at best
Have looked  under /usr/local/share/fish/completions/*, found nothing resembling
(ignoring the fact that '[' is a shell special char, in a first attempt )
Thanks very much in advance for any hints!

Are the brackets part of the argument - that is is somecmd -k foo[arg1] the thing you want to match? Or are you hoping to match somecmd -k foo arg1? Please share a literal string that you want to complete.

Thanks for the answer. The top level completion is ok (hat is -k  The complete line would be zabbi_get -s 127.0.0.1 -k net.if.in[NameOfTheInterface,Type]

I wish to complete the NameOfTheInterface and Type parts. After extensive testing, I get the impression that the '[' character gets in the way ...
